# Magento 2 Custom Form Validation Not Working

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation

I have built a custom CMS form page in Magento 2 that sends an email with the results. The form loads correctly, and the email is generated correctly, but the form validation is not working. If the required fields are not filled out, it still sends the request to the post controller and displays a blank page. When hitting the back button it will show a validation error, but only for the email field. I've tried several methods of Magento form validation with the same results on each. What am I missing?

This is the .phtml file view template that displays the form.

```
<form class="form" action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'customemail/index/post/';?>" name="customemaildata" method="post" id="contactForm-1" data-hasrequired="<?php echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>

<fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Name') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo __('Name') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate='{"required":true}'/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Phone') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="phone" id="phone" title="<?php echo __('Phone') ?>" class="input-text" type="tel" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phonelax':true}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Is your hair thick or thin?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="thickthin" id="thickthin"  title="<?php echo __('Option Name') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required true}">
                    <option value=""><?php echo __('Please select a choice') ?></option>
                    <option value="Thick"><?php echo __('Thick') ?></option>
                    <option value="Thin"><?php echo __('Thin') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Is your oily or dry?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="oilydry" id="oilydry"  title="<?php echo __('Option Name') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required true}">
                    <option value=""><?php echo __('Please select a choice') ?></option>
                    <option value="Oily"><?php echo __('Oily') ?></option>
                    <option value="Dry"><?php echo __('Dry') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Is your hair frizzy at all?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="frizzy" id="frizy"  title="<?php echo __('Option Name') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required true}">
                    <option value=""><?php echo __('Please select a choice') ?></option>
                    <option value="Very frizzy"><?php echo __('Very Frizzy') ?></option>
                    <option value="Some frizzy"><?php echo __('Parially Frizzy') ?></option>
                    <option value="Not frizzy"><?php echo __('Not Frizzy') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Do you use heat on your hair?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="heat" id="heat"  title="<?php echo __('Option Name') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required true}">
                    <option value=""><?php echo __('Please select a choice') ?></option>
                    <option value="Yes"><?php echo __('Yes') ?></option>
                    <option value="No"><?php echo __('No') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Is your hair curly, straight, or wavy?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="curlystraightwavy" id="curlystraightwavy"  title="<?php echo __('Option Name') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required true}">
                    <option value=""><?php echo __('Please select a choice') ?></option>
                    <option value="Curly"><?php echo __('Curly') ?></option>
                    <option value="Straight"><?php echo __('Straight') ?></option>
                    <option value="Wavy"><?php echo __('Wavy') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Do you bleach your hair?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="bleach" id="bleach"  title="<?php echo __('Option Name') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required true}">
                    <option value=""><?php echo __('Please select a choice') ?></option>
                    <option value="Yes"><?php echo __('Yes') ?></option>
                    <option value="No"><?php echo __('No') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

            <script>
                    function yesnoCheck(that) {
                            if (that.value!="None") {
                                    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
                            } else {
                                    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
                            }
                    }
            </script>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Do you have any breakage or thinning anywhere, and if so where?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="breakagethinning" id="breakagethinning"  title="<?php echo __('Option Name') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required true}" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
                    <option value=""><?php echo __('Please select a choice') ?></option>
                    <option value="Breakage"><?php echo __('Breakage') ?></option>
                    <option value="Thinning"><?php echo __('Thinning') ?></option>
                    <option value="None"><?php echo __('None') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="field email" id="ifYes" style="display:none;">
                    <label class"label" for="email"><span><?php echo __('Where at?') ?></span></label>
                    <input name="where" id="where" title="<?php echo __('Where') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:false}"/>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('What products do you use now?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="products" id="products" title="<?php echo __('Products') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('What would you like to change about your hair?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="changes" id="changes" title="<?php echo __('Changes') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
            <span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you use simple HTML form validation? Isn't that working?

Comment: That was way to easy. Yes, basic HTML validation works. I still don't understand why Magento's documented validation isn't though.